# Remove array from object if great grandchildren arrays are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

So I have an object which has a structure like

```
object.childArrays.grandchildArrays.greatgrandchildArrays
```

I want to remove the child array if any of the subsequent arrays are empty. (also can't use es6 :'( )

Example object

```
object[
  [2019, [items, [docs, ['a', 'b', 'c']], [docs, ['d', 'e', 'f']]]], 
  [2018, [items, [docs, []]]],
  [2017, [items, [docs, ['x', 'y', 'z']]]],
]
```

2018 would be removed.

```
object[
  [2019, [items, [docs, ['a', 'b', 'c']], [docs, ['d', 'e', 'f']]]], 
  [2017, [items, [docs, ['x', 'y', 'z']]]],
]
```

Comment: So what is an example object and what should it look like when done?

Comment: any snippet or something you tried?

Comment: Give an example object, and what you tried, and people are more likely to be eager to help. Otherwise they have to spend time trying to work out what you mean. For example, by "subsequent", presumably you mean deeper in the hierarchy? To put it another way, am I right in understanding that you are asking to leave no empty arrays anywhere in the tree? --- Excellent, thanks for the Edit, I will try to answer.

Comment: @epascarello I've added an example to try and better demonstrate what I meant. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: @Eureka let me know if that's a good enough explanation. If not I can try and do more.

Comment: Your example "object" is actually a nested array. So are you talking about arrays or really an object? If the latter, please provide a proper example structure.

Comment: @Myles, I am wondering whether what you mean by your object. I have given two interpretations of your original question, but neither seems acceptable to you. Could you kindly give an example of an actual working Javascript (not pseudocode) so that we can see unambigiously what you mean? We really are putting effort into trying to help you. 8-)

Answer (score 0):

#### Assuming "items" and "docs" are strings or some other sort of item, this would do it:

```js
function recursivelyRemoveEmptyArrays(source){
  if (Array.isArray(source)){
    const resultArray =[]
    source.forEach(oneSource=>{
      const oneResult = recursivelyRemoveEmptyArrays(oneSource);
      if (!Array.isArray(oneResult) || oneResult.length>0){
         resultArray.push(oneResult)}
      })
      return resultArray
   } else {
     return source
   }
   
}

const example=[
  [2019, ["items", ["docs", ['a', 'b', 'c']]],  ["docs", ['d', 'e', 'f']]], 
  [2018, ["items", ["docs", []]]],
  [2017, ["items", ["docs", ['x', 'y', 'z']]]],
];

console.log(recursivelyRemoveEmptyArrays(example))
```

However, it is removing not "2018", but just the deep empty array: [].
The arrays outside that are not empty, because they each contain something e.g. "docs".

Comment: I would need 2018 removed as well. That's the tricky part.

Answer (score 0):

So make a recursive method to see if all the nested indexes of the arrays have data. Loop over, if it does not remove it.

```js
const items = [1];
const docs = [2];
const data = [
  [2019, [items, [docs, ['a', 'b', 'c']], [docs, ['d', 'e', 'f']]]], 
  [2018, [items, [docs, []]]],
  [2017, [items, [docs, ['x', 'y', 'z']]]],
];

var hasValues = arr => {
  return arr.every(item => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        return (item.length === 0) ? false : hasValues(item);
    } else {
      return item !== undefined; // whatever your truthy check should be
    }
  })
}

for (let i = data.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
  if (!hasValues(data[i])) {
     data.splice(i, 1)
  }
}

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

#### However if you have intended your "items" and "docs" to in fact be keys in an object, then this is what you need

Here I am assuming that the array part of the data always starts at the same level, i.e. you have a year number level, and underneath it an item level, and underneath it a docs level, and only inside that do you begin to have arrays.

```js
const example = {
  2019: {
    items: {
      docs: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
  },
  2018: {
    items: {
      docs: []
    }
  },
  2017: {
    items: {
      docs: ['x', 'y', 'z']
    }
  },
};


const out = {}

Object.keys(example).forEach(child => { // e.g. 2019
  let nArrayItems = 0;
  Object.keys(example[child]).forEach(grandchild => {
    Object.keys(example[child][grandchild]).forEach(greatgrandchild => {
      nArrayItems += example[child][grandchild][greatgrandchild].length; // This assumes you are confident the greatgrandchild will be an array, so that you can safely rely on its length. If there is a danger that it may be a string, you should be more careful with this step.

    })
  })
  if (nArrayItems > 0) {
    out[child] = example[child]
  }
})


console.log(out)
```

Comment: Hi @Myles. Why the -1? I was just trying with a different interpretation of the Object in your question. If I have interpreted it wrongly, please comment on why the interpretation is incorrect, otherwise people are discouraged from trying to help you.

Comment: Maybe because when you originally posted it you had nothing but the heading.